# Getting around two dimensional array prohibition

Tags: verilog

The textbook I just bought, *Verilog HDL: A Guide to Digital Design and Synthesis* by Samir Palnitkar, says it's impossible to have a two-dimensional array directly, but someone who's used Verilog says there's a way to work around that. Furthermore, if my quasi-two-dimensional array is value "outer" and i does not equal j, then the array associated with "outer[i]" is not necessarily of the same length as the array associated with "outer[j]". Can anyone tell me how to code this in Verilog?

Answer (score 1):

Two dimensional arrays are perfectly allowed in Verilog. They can be mapped to registers or memories.

Two dimensional arrays are not allowed in **ports**. For that I would recommend you switch to system Verilog.

What is not possible to synthesize, in either language is "column" access.

```
// array of 16 register each 4 bits wide.
reg [3:0] two_D [0:15];
...
   // This is fine 
   for (row=0; row<8; row=row+1)
      my_row = two_D[row]; 
   // You can also take a slice from that:
   assign top_right_2bits =two_D[0][3:2]; 
...
   // Column access only works in simulation
   for (col=0; col<16; col=col+1)
      my_col = {two_D[3][col],two_D[2][col],two_D[1][col],two_D[0][col]};
```

For details you have to look-up packed versus unpacked arrays.

Comment: Your example of a two-dimensional array was encouraging, but it still fixed the dimensions as four by sixteen. I need an array of arrays, and the lengths of the second arrays are at times going to be different from each other. For example, the array associated with "outer[0]" might have length seventeen, the array associated with "outer[1]" might have length eight, the array associated with "outer[2]" length four, and so on. How can I do that in Verilog?

Comment: Unfortunately Verilog can't do that. There is no simple hardware equivalent on which that maps. You can either build a system where you do not use the short vectors, thus build a 2-D array for the maximum vector. Or you have to make a more complex system with some sort of pointers in memory and gather up multiple vectors in several clock cycles where the memory width is less then the array you need.

Comment: This is really frustrating. I'm just trying, with parameter k, to build a machine to compare two operands, each k bits long, and output one bit, a logical one if the first operand is less than the second, and a logical zero if it is not, and to do it as efficiently as possible for all values, and taking roughly the same amoun6t of time for all values. I had thought I had three choices. (1) I could do it with a one-dimensional array and waste log(k) bits of storage. (2) I could do it with an array of arrays (where the latter arrays vary in length) and waste at most two bits of storage. ...

Comment: ... Or (3) I could write a Java program that takes a value of k as input, and writes Verilog that has the equivalent of "and (eq[4][0], eq[5][0], eq[5][1])" as "and (eq_4_0, eq_5_0, eq_5_1)", and then I wouldn't have to waste any storage space at all. I was leaning towards option (2), but I'm getting mixed signals on that; one poster said I could do (2) in Verilog but didn't tell me how, and now here Oldfart is telling me I CAN'T do it in Verilog. The former poster seemed to think I could enclose the variable-size array in some kind of structure, and make an array of that structure, ...

Comment: ... perhaps involving pointers to the variable sized arrays. Can we come to some kind of consensus about whether this is possible?

Comment: *"Oldfart is telling me I CAN'T it in Verilog"* we seem to have a misunderstanding, You can't do it **directly** in Verilog. As I stated: you *can* do it using a sort of pointers in memory, which is in fact the scheme what @dave_59 is describing.

Comment: It is the same we used in old FORTRAN programming. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can always a mapping function that takes any number of dimensions and linearizes them into a single dimension. You start by defining an linear array with a single dimension large enough to hold all the elements it needs

```
reg [DATA_SIZE-1:0] mem[0:TOTAL_SIZE];
```

Then you define a function that takes in any number of indexes you want and returns a single index based on any kind of mapping you want. This is exactly what any programming language would do

```
function int calculate_index(int D1, D2);
 // whatever code and mapping tables
endfunction
...
mem[calculate_index(X,Y)+:DATA_SIZE);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had to do this once. My solution was to rotate the 2 dimensional array (mxn) 90 degrees to make a second 2 dimensional (nxm) array. Accessing vectors form this second array is the same as column access of the first array. Since the second array is simply a wire assign or equivalent, no logic is created, and it is synthesizable.